# Make Div with text responsive using VW?

Tags: html, css

Currently, I am using units: "vw" to make my textbox responsive.

**First fiddle (Non-responsive)**: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/w7yhd6xx/2/

```css
#second{
 height:635px;
  background:gray;

}
#second-try{
  height:635px;
}
.about-us-info {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 900px;
 height: 313px;
 border: 2px solid #3c3c3c;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -450px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -160px;
}
span.span-header {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 /* margin-top: -22px; */
 position: relative;
 font-size: 34px;
 background: white;
 width: 420px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -21px;
 /* border: 1px solid black; */
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: latobold;
 letter-spacing: .16em;
}

.about-us-info p {
 text-align: center;
 /* line-height: 28px; */
 line-height: 1.65em;

}
.about-us-info p.first {

 margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="second">
  
  <div class="about-us-info">
   <span class="span-header">About Us</span>
   <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a turpis non est commodo mollis.   <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a turpis non est commodo mollis.
   </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Second fiddle (Attempt at responsiveness using "*vw*"):**https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/9Lagw1y6/1/

```css
.section{
  position:relative;
}

#second{
 min-height:635px;

}

.about-us-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 46.9vw;
    /* height: 16.3vw; */
    border: 2px solid #3c3c3c;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -23.4vw;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;
}span.span-header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    /* margin-top: -22px; */
    position: relative;
    font-size: 34px;
    background: white;
    width: 420px;
    width: 21.875vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -21px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: latobold;
    letter-spacing: .16em;
}

.about-us-info p {
 text-align: center;
 /* line-height: 28px; */
 line-height: 1.65em;

}
.about-us-info p.first {

 margin-top:50px;
}

/*----Third section--------*/

#third{
 min-height:488px;
  background:gray;
}

#services-info{

 margin-top:-125px;
 border:2px solid white;
 border-top:0px;
}
#services-header{
 background:transparent;
 color:white;

}
#services-paragraph{
 color:white;
}
#services-header:before, #services-header:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    top: 19px;
    width: 11.8vw;
}
#services-header:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: .85vw;
}
#services-header:after {
 left: 100%;
 margin-left: .85vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="second">
  
  <div class="about-us-info">
   <span class="span-header">About Us</span>
   <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a turpis non est commodo mollis.   <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a turpis non est commodo mollis.
   </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  
   <div class="section" id="third">
  <div class="about-us-info" id="services-info">
   <span class="span-header" id="services-header">Services</span>
   <p class="first" id="services-paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here are some errors that I'd like to be corrected but not sure how to:
1.) Is VW being used properly here?  Is there a better solution?
2.) I'd like the height of each section to expand based on the content within while maintaining a min-height of each section (635px for the first and 488 for the second) because right now when re-sizing the browser smaller, the content overlaps anything underneath it.

Is there any problem using this solution?  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Simply put, you are doing it wrong. To understand my point, just resize your browser to mobile size. My best offer is to code it properly for you (I make a gift every Friday). Before I start coding it, please clarify how you want it displayed on desktop|tablet|mobile. As it is now it's not clear.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.  So basically, I would like each section to be a minimum height, but when the browser resizes, I'd like each section to be able to adjust accordingly to fit the content within, I'd say a padding bottom of 50.  I would like the content box (the div with the border) to be a minimum of 300px while scaling height accordingly to the content inside.  The header font size below 800px should be 1.25em.  That's it really, I just don't want the sections to overlap while retaining the content.  I can clarify if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this it? If not, let me know.

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.sections {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
            align-items: stretch;
}
.sections section {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 50%;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 50%;
          flex: 1 0 50%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
.sections section>div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
        -ms-flex-item-align: center;
            align-self: center;
    padding: 35px 50px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin: 50px 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: min-width .3s ease-out;
    transition: min-width .3s ease-out;
}
#second {
  background-color: white;
  color: #333;
} 
#third >div {
  border-color: white;
}
#third {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.span-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: font-size .3s ease-out;
    transition: font-size .3s ease-out;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#third .span-header {
  background-color: gray;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sections section>div{
    min-width: 60%;
  }
  .sections section>div {
    padding: 15px 30px;
  }
  .span-header {
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 359px) {
  .sections section>div{
    min-width: calc(100vw - 120px);
  }
  .span-header {
    white-space: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sections">
  <section id="second">
    <div class="about-us-info">
      <span class="span-header">About Us</span>
      <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a turpis non est commodo mollis.
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a turpis non est commodo mollis.
      </p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="third">
    <div class="about-us-info" id="services-info">
      <span class="span-header" id="services-header">Services</span>
      <p class="first" id="services-paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Please note I've also made a few adjustments to the html markup. Cheers!

<kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1o3bgr3c/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much, would you mind if I sent you my code for proofreading, don't feel bad to say no, I'd just like a more seasoned developer to look at it and see what they think about it.

Comment: Sure, I'll have a look.

Comment: https://github.com/jasonzhang172/Test-Landing-Page

The psd is attached to what I'm trying to make it look like.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Mail me using my website's contact form so we can talk. I only got about another hour today. Tomorrow's fine also, if you don't have time now.

Comment: I have time today and tomorrow :D, where can I find your website contact form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104001/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-snorlax).

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

It is perfectly fine to use `vw` this way. Percentage widths can generally do the same things as `vw`, but since you have some nesting, you would have to mess with the parent's widths to make percentages work. (This use case was [noted by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).)

The nesting I'm talking about is `<div class="section">`s. Since the margins on the `<body` element have not been reset, these sections (on some browsers) end up a little narrower than the viewport. To use percentages, you would have to do this:

```css
/* Reset margins */
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Now use percentages */
.about-us-info {
    width: 46.9%;
}

span.span-header {
    width: 47.4%;
}
```

Note `vw` has more issues with [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) (look at the known issues tab).

## Question 2

In the code given, the text boxes are using `position: absolute` as part of the centering. Absolute positioning takes elements out of the document flow, and that is the reason the sections are not expanding to fit the content. If you want them to expand properly, you will need to use a [different centering technique](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

CSS table centering (as shown in the link above) would work:

```
<!-- First wrap your text boxes with containers... -->

<div class="section" id="second">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="about-us-info">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then remove the current absolute-based centering on the text boxes and add the following:

```css
/* Make the parent a table: */
.section {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Make the container a table cell and center it: */
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```